# Get RSS feed from iTunes podcast links

Tags: itunes, rss, podcasts, feed

I'm using Gnome's Rhythmbox to listen to Podcasts. Some Podcasts don't provide an rss feed for downloading the episodes but only a `itms://` link for iTunes.

Now I'd like to download them via a "normal" RSS reader/podfetcher.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: People answering are ignoring the itms:// part of your question and assuming you're referring to normal iTunes links. Those are two different types of links. See my answer for a direct response to your question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should first subscribe to the Podcast using iTunes, then open your iTunes library.

If you go to your Podcasts listing in your iTunes library, you will see a list of the Podcasts you subscribe to. Right-click on the Podcast you want to copy the URL of and select "Copy Podcast URL". This will copy the URL to the RSS feed of the Podcast into your clipboard. You can then paste that link into whatever other application you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Is there a possibility _without_ using iTunes?

Comment: I have not found a way to get the feed URL without using iTunes (and assuming the site doesn't publish the feed URL anywhere). Often it's so time-consuming to search/guess at what the URL would be that it's easier to just open up iTunes and do it that way. I sympathize with the desire to bypass iTunes entirely and will watch this thread to see if anyone comes up with a way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your research. I will post my information too, if I found sth new.

Comment: Is Apple literally trying to break the web!?

Comment: HaveAGuess... Apple is trying to BREAK EVERYTHING!

Comment: I also found it very useful to get my podcast's feed url so I built this tool: http://podcastlookup.com let me know if you have any suggestions to improve it!

Comment: @Erwan Suggestion: Make it work ;] (details: all queries fail to find the forms action url, details.html, so it ist b0rk)

Answer (score 84):

You can use the following "small tool" I created to do this:

[Itunes podcast link extractor](http://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/2mb5C/) (Just enter an iTunes podcast URL in the input field)

**How it works if you prefer to do it manually**:

Extract the Id from the link with a regex or somethin else

EX: `https://itunes.apple.com/podcast/state-trance-official-podcast/id260190086`

load this link with the ID
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=260190086&entity=podcast

Get the `feedUrl` from this json file.

The `&entity=podcast` is not necessary but it may help

Country code may be required outside the US, eg: `&country=au`

Comment: This is not related to ITMS links. You're answering "How to extract the RSS feed from a normal iTunes link?" but that's not what OP asked.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Found this page while searching for `itunes podcast rss url`, so this answer is still relevant.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. ex: https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/how-to-program-with-java/id563384781

Comment: It worked for me (audio podcast). The one you posted Dummy looks like a video podcast (iTunes U), maybe you need a different format.

Comment: Just tested and it worked for me as well!  In Chrome, it will download a .txt with the info inside of it.

Comment: This trick worked for me just now.

Comment: It works for me in June 2021

Comment: This works only if the podcaster is still displaying their feed url.

Answer (score 34):

This works also: http://picklemonkey.net/feedflipper-home/
You can even see the original iTunes feed when you open the generated feed in your browser.

Comment: This is really the best solution without installing and running iTunes.. more so now that I am on Ubuntu...

Comment: This is a good one. Took me literally less than 1 minute to get the direct RSS feed link. Thanks so much!

Comment: The link seems dead now.

Comment: Dead for me, too. I recommend @Gino's solution, below.

Comment: Also, `http://picklemonkey.net/feedflipper-home/` will do the trick. Thanks, @senarvi!

Comment: I also needed to find my podcasts urls, so I built this tool: http://podcastlookup.com.

Comment: It's not obvious, but the old not-working link reported above was replaced with a working one in an edit.

Comment: Works perfectly. Needed this to find a client's RSS feed and didn't want to have to subscribe via iTunes to the podcast myself.

Answer (score 4):

I believe all the existing answers are mistaken. The itms protocol is used when a podcast is not listed on iTunes at all. It's used as a shortcut to subscribe a regular RSS feed that isn't on iTunes. It's a way to allow someone to subscribe to iTunes without having the feed listed in the directory.

It works simply by replacing the http:// protocol prefix of an RSS feed URL with itms:// So, if you'd like to get the regular RSS feed of a show that's linking to itms, just replace the itms with http.

Here's an example: A show I help produce is called Keith and The Girl. Their RSS feed is http://www.keithandthegirl.com/rss Their iTunes link listing is https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/keith-girl-comedy-talk-show/id253167631?mt=2&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

However, you can subscribe to the RSS feed directly by replacing the http in the RSS feed url with ITMS like so itms://www.keithandthegirl.com/rss (SE won't let me make that link clickable but you get the idea)

So, now you see that ITMS and HTTP are interchangeable. Whenever you encounter an ITMS link, just replace it with HTTP.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Simply sends me back to the iTunes page from which I got the original ITMSS link. @Gino's solution, however, works fine. It gives me a URL I can put into my RSS feed reader and forget about.

Comment: Great but @Gino is answering a question that wasn't asked. Gino is answering "How do I get the RSS link from a typical iTunes podcast link?" The original question is related to "ITMS://" links. My answer specifically addresses the original question. Gino addresses a different question related to RSS feeds and iTunes. It has nothing to do with ITMS links.

Answer (score 2):

iTunes Podcast Feed Extractor is an online tool I've created for reliably extracting an RSS url from an iTunes podcast link  (so any podcast/rss app can be used). https://votable.net/tools/itunes.php

## Instructions

- Copy and paste the relevant URL into the input field on the page. (The URL protocol doesn't matter e.g. "https", "itms," etc.)
- Click the submit button
- The extracted RSS URL should appear in below the form (along with the title and a thumbnail). If the feed could not be extracted, you will see an error message in the same area.
- Now you can use the real RSS URL in your desired podcast/RSS app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Podcast Lookup](https://www.labnol.org/podcast/) tool to get the RSS feed of any Apple Podcast show.

[image: Apple Podcast RSS Feed]

Comment: Thanks @amit-agarwal, this is the best tool I have seen out there!

Comment: Thank you @jhbsk

Answer (score 0):

While searching for a way to do this, I found [Find out the RSS feed for an iTunes podcast](https://www.djm.org.uk/posts/reveal-rss-feed-url-itunes-podcast/). The guy created a bookmarklet `to reveal the true RSS podcast URL/content feed`, when you are on an iTunes podcast page.

```
javascript:(function(){var%20newScript=document.createElement('script');newScript.src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/djm/uncover-itunes-rss-bookmarklet/master/bookmarklet.js';document.body.appendChild(newScript);})();
```

It should be noted that the bookmarklet redirects to `https://cdn.rawgit.com/djm/uncover-itunes-rss-bookmarklet/master/bookmarklet.js`. It looks innocuous enough but the script could be changed at any time, including by a malicious hacker, so be forewarned.

He did publish it on `GitHub`––[djm/uncover-itunes-rss-bookmarklet: Javascript bookmarklet to reveal actual RSS URL on a iTunes podcast page](https://github.com/djm/uncover-itunes-rss-bookmarklet).

It works. e.g., when on `https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/burnt-toast/id969524107?mt=2`, the bookmarklet gave me `http://feeds.feedburner.com/food52burnttoast`. This opened perfectly in my feed reader.

Comment: [rawgit is being discontinued](http://web.archive.org/web/20190105230952/https://rawgit.com/)

Comment: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/djm/uncover-itunes-rss-bookmarklet@75cb5d6a6ae2870b6c4da46e929cf84b3eda3028/bookmarklet.js should work as a replacement. By using the commit hash instead of `master`, it also reduces the set of people able to do injection from djm, github and jsdelivr (or in the original, rawgit) to just github and jsdelivr.