# How to download a podcast without iTunes?

Tags: download, rss, podcasts

I just want the .mp3 file. I don't want any of the other crap that comes included. I intend to just listen to this on a burned audio cd in the car.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/stuff-you-should-know/id278981407

Thanks.

Edit: Even better if I don't have to download any software at all. I just want the MP3 files in a simple list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are direct links to the mp3s in the [RSS feed](http://www.howstuffworks.com/podcasts/stuff-you-should-know.rss).

For a general way to get a podcast's RSS feed, please check the following superuser question: [Get RSS feed from iTunes podcast links](https://superuser.com/questions/78415/get-rss-feed-from-itunes-podcast-links?rq=1)

Comment: This doesn't really work for generic iTunes podcasts, just this example.

Comment: From my experience, many podcasts offer an RSS feed on their websites, but you are totally right in pointing out that this doesn't apply to all.

Comment: I've just edited my question to make it more general, hope that helps.

Comment: Note: Works on Firefox, but somehow not on Chrome (shows up as a bunch of html code).

Answer (score 3):

This is how I got it (so you can try it yourself):

1. I Googled `Stuff You Should Know RSS Feed` and chose [the first result](http://www.howstuffworks.com/podcasts/stuff-you-should-know.rss).
2. In Firefox, IE, or Safari (basically anything but Chrome), you can scroll through the list and pick and choose the ones you want. To download one, just do a Right Click->Save As.
   Thanks for introducing me to a great podcast, by the way :-).

Comment: or add the RSS link to your feed reader (e.g. Google Reader) and then download from there.

Comment: Not too convenient though, when you only want to download one episode.  
But duly noted.

Answer (score 3):

I just used this: http://podbay.fm/. You can listen online or download - pretty impressed with it TBH!

Comment: @ChrisF OK, I didn't realise that, thanks! Not sure why my answer's being downvoted though. Podbay is a nice website with podcasts you can download...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the RSS feed of an iTunes podcast using an online tool, from there you can extract mp3 urls:

https://votable.net/tools/itunes.php