# Listen to a ITunes podcast without using ITunes?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

How do I listen to / download the files from a (free) ITunes podcast?

The following question [How to download a podcast without iTunes?](https://superuser.com/questions/178720/how-to-download-a-podcast-without-itunes) suggests that I open the RSS feed to get the audio links.

The problem is that I can't find the RSS feed anywhere, just a "View in Itunes" link.

Wanted podcast:
http://itunes.apple.com/podcast/danz-20-countdown-maxwell/id341032245

Comment: But without iTunes, how will you sync it to your iPhone???

Comment: It was undoubtedly (reasonably good) sarcasm.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found a tool at this website http://itunes.so-nik.com which will tell you the actual RSS feed from an iTunes store link.

For example, when given:
http://itunes.apple.com/podcast/danz-20-countdown-maxwell/id341032245

It returns: http://data.radiodanz.com/danz20/danz20.rss

---

The iTunes Store (iTS) does not actually host or publish feeds. See [here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html):

> Understanding the iTunes Client and the iTunes Store.
>
> ...
>
> When you submit your podcast, you are notifying iTS that you have a podcast feed that is located in a particular location (the feed URL). If your feed is accepted, iTS simply reads your feed each day and updates the podcast directory with any new or changed information about your podcast. **Note that iTS does not cache or make a copy of your feed, nor does it cache or make a copy of your episode files.** For podcasts, iTS is acting in a capacity similar to a web directory.
>
> When users find interesting podcasts in iTS, they click the Subscribe button, **causing the podcast feed URL to be copied from iTS to the user's iTunes client.** The iTunes client reads the podcast feed that is located at the feed URL, **then downloads the media file for the podcast's most recent episode from the web server where it is hosted**.

Comment: The `http://itunes.so-nik.com` link is dead. Any alternatives?

Comment: This worked for me: https://www.djm.org.uk/posts/reveal-rss-feed-url-itunes-podcast/.

In case that link dies too, grab the "ID" from the itunes podcast url, and plug it into `http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=341032245`.  Look for `feedUrl` in the resulting json.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to http://www.podfeed.net/podcast/The+Danz+20+Countdown+with+Maxwell+House/19317 and download or listen to the podcast.

Answer (score 0):

Found a forum post with the links: http://www.radiodanz.com/Internet-Dance-Radio/community/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=673&hilit=podcast

However, I'll accept any answer that shows how one can get the RSS feed from itunes.com

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the URL of the feed that iTunes checks, right-clicking the podcast (but not a particular episode) and choosing "Copy podcast URL" will copy the feed URL to your clipboard.

*Note: my iTunes is in Dutch so the translation of 'Podcast-URL kopiëren' might differ from your installation.*

Comment: I don't have ITunes installed (and can't install it either, company policy). I would have listened on it through ITunes otherwise.